# Got org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing when modified the hbase.coprocessor.region.classes in hbase-site.xml

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, observers

Guys, I am trying to add a region observer to hbase, the code is like:

```
public class TestAddColumnBaseRegionObserver extends BaseRegionObserver{

@Override

public void prePut(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e, Put put, WALEdit edit, Durability durability) throws IOException {

     putUUIDColumnIfMissing(e, put, edit, durability);

}

private void     putUUIDColumnIfMissing(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> e, Put put,  WALEdit edit, Durability durability) {

    try {

        if(!put.has(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("uuid"))) {

        String uuid = put.toString(); // md5

        put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("uuid"), Bytes.toBytes(uuid));

}

} catch (Exception e1) {

     e1.printStackTrace();

}

}

}
```

so this code would add a new column "uuid" to the table if there is no "cf1:uuid" column in the table.

it works when I manually added the .jar in the hbase shell, but when doing another way: modify the hbase-site.xml, by modifying the hbase.coprocessor.region.classes to the TestAddColumnBaseRegionObserver class

```
<property>

<name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>

<value>com.hbase.hook.TestAddColumnBaseRegionObserver</value>

</property>
```

and restart the hbase, I got an error reported when logged into the hbase shell and tred to do a hbase command

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing   at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:2177) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkNamespaceManagerReady(HMaster.java:2182) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.ensureNamespaceExists(HMaster.java:2375) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1444) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:48502) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Did anyone meet similar problems before? Or do you know what causes this problem?